# Is there a way to use Flex 9-slice scaling at runtime?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I haven't been able to find an answer to this online. Is there a way to use 9-slice scaling with images loaded at runtime?

To clarify, let's say that I build an application that lets a user skin a button with whatever image they want. This would be an image that's not embedded with the swf. Is there a way to set that runtime image as a background and use 9-scaling?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a rectangle as the scale9grid of a movieClip that contains your image art.

http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/scale9/

Now, to use a MovieClip in Flex (it's a Flash thingy) you have to load it into a UIComponent:

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_You_wish_to_add_a_Sprite_or_MovieClip_to_a_Flex_ap-7142.html